# Disabling compression on HTTP requests

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, http-accept-encoding

I have a web service that a customer calls with no Accept-Encoding header today. By default, IIS gzips responses back unless the server is under too much load, in which case the responses go back uncompressed (as is consistent with [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding)):

> The server is overloaded and cannot afford the computational overhead
>   induced by the compression requirement. Typically, Microsoft
>   recommends not to compress if a server use more than 80 % of its
>   computational power.

However, their system doesn't appear able to handle this 'dynamic' response. They say they can either request gzip and get gzip back or request uncompressed and get that back. It doesn't appear we can FORCE our server to respond with gzip so the alternative is to uncompress all responses.

I'm not a low-level HTTP expert so, is this the sort of `Accept-Encoding` header I could use to force uncompressed responses?

```
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1.0, *;q=0.0
```